Attempt to remap C-c a ignored in Doom emacs
I'm trying out doom emacs and so far it's fun, though I don't use evil-mode.
My regular emacs has org agenda bound to C-c a:
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
But I can not get doom to get this to work.  I've tried:
(map! :map 'override "C-c a" #'org-agenda)
(map! :map 'override "C-c c" #'org-capture)

(map! :after org "C-c a" #'org-agenda)

in a super simple config.el with no luck.
And the odd thing is that if I doom/reload, it works fine.
I suspect I am doing something odd / not putting the code in the right place, but google seems to have no answers here.
Thanks for any help!
I tried:
(map! :map 'override "C-c a" #'org-agenda)
(map! :map 'override "C-c c" #'org-capture)

(map! :after org "C-c a" #'org-agenda)

And I expected that C-c a would get me org-agenda, but it brings up embark-act instead.
